# Scottish vs. scotch

Tags: comparisons

I looked up the dictionary, and both gave me definitions that refer to a people from Scotland. Is there a difference between these two words?

Comment: Scotchy scotch scotch goes into your belly; the other one usually doesn't.

Comment: Is that an Anchorman reference? ;)

Comment: "Ususally." Teeheehee.

Comment: Another one is "Scots", as in "Scots language".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Wikipedia has an article on [Scotch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scotch_%28adjective%29).  Essentially it is the old version of the adjective, while Scots and Scottish are more common now. The people are *Scots* as a noun, as in "He is a Scot" or "He is Scottish".

The best line in the article is:

> One cynical joke is that Scotch can be
>   used only for things which can be
>   bought, such as whisky, eggs and
>   politicians.

Comment: *tape* should be included in that list!

Comment: @Jimi Oke: Not in the UK (which at the time of writing still includes Scotland) it shouldn't!